# Tense in the given context

Tags: tense

Is the following sentence correct?

> if I was supposed to send friend requests only to my acquaintances,
>   why would I have come here?

Comment: Yes it's correct. Why did you doubt it?

Comment: In my first version, I wrote a present form in the first clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I was supposed to send friend requests only to my acquaintances, why would I have come here?

The sentence seems grammatically correct, although I don't understand the context because you haven't really given any. Your sentence implies that sending friend requests only to acquaintances, and coming "here" are mutually exclusive, but we don't know where "here" is, so I can't confirm that it makes sense.

However, assuming that it makes sense to you, yes everything looks in order. Structurally, it matches this sentence:

> If I was supposed to buy only milk, why would I have come to a bakery?